# As per Advaita, Atman/Self/Brahman is unborn and doesnt "pass" away when body dies? What is the reference for it?

Tags: advaita, vedanta, upanishads, atma, rebirth

As per Advaita Vedanta, its the Sukshma Sharira(Subtle Body/Mind) which reincarnates after a body dies and Atman/Brahman/Self does not "pass away" or "leave" when body dies. But in few Upanishadic passages below, I find contradictory statements that Atman passes off when body dies. Could I get better clarification and sources to prove Brahman/Atman is unborn from Upanishads only and that the mind/subtle body/Sukshma Sharira reincarnates, but Atman does not and is always there?

Contradictory verses :

> The father said; ‘O Somya, know this: When the self leaves the body,
> the body surely dies. The self, however, never dies. That which is the
> subtlest of all is the Self of all this. (Chandogya Upanishad 6.11.3)
>
> He who is thus born of his own self, becomes the substitute for
> performing the deeds. After completing his works, he departs.
> Departing thus he is born again. This is his third birth. This what
> the seers said. (Aitareya Upanishad 2.2.4)

Comment: A subtle body IS NOT a real body. It is as mayaic as a physical one. Advaita Vedanta doesn't refer to *Sukshma Sharira* as Atman/Brahman. The property of Brahman is someone who is unborn and is NOT supposed to be limited to any attribute, unlike the subtile body.